# Have toggleClass fade in but not fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using the `toggleClass()` method with jQuery and I'd like to have the class fade in, but I don't want it to fade out.  I've been using the "duration" attribute, but given that it is toggleClass, the duration is the same both ways.  I don't want to use `addClass()` with a fade in and `removeClass()` without a fade out because I feel like the code will get too lengthy and unruly.  I want small, simple, readable code.

Any ideas?

I have this so far:

```
$("#e" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("#word").toggleClass("hoverE", 500 )
});
```

I would like something like this where I can specify fade in duration and fade out duration:

```
$("#e" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("#word").toggleClass("hoverE", 500, 0 )
});
```

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#e" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("#word").toggleClass("hoverE").fadeIn(500)
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="word">
    <h1><a id="h" class= "letter" href=#>H</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="e" class= "letter" href=#>E</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l" class= "letter" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l2"class= "letter" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="o" class= "letter" href=#>O</a></h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: I assume that you are using jquery ui, as `toggleClass` normally doesn't have a duration.

Comment: So when you use the `closest` function, you are walking up through parent divs to find `#word`. If you can hover on `#e` in the first place, it has to be visible. That means the parent (`#word`) also has to be visible, which means it can't be faded in.

Comment: I have been fading it in and out.  It fades in when I hover over the element, but fades out when I hover out.  I don't want it to fade out.

Comment: Ok, so when the "E" is hovered, which element is it that you want to fade in? The rest of the letters? Are all the other letters hidden by default?

Comment: I should be more clear.  When I hover over the letter, the #word element fades in/out, not the actual letter.  Which is why I'm using closest. I'll look at the fiddle.

Comment: Since the "e" element is contained in the #word element, when the word element fades out, the e element will too, and you wont be able to get it to fade back in. Is that your intent? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5MScN/2/

Comment: @JeffEscalante I am having the background color change.  So the letters are unaffected.  The #word encompasses the entire background which is why I am changing that element.

Comment: Still trying to guess what effect you're after exactly - is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/5MScN/5/

Comment: Yes actually.  That affect is working the way I had hoped.  I noticed you doing the transition effect for #word.  That is what I ended up doing after playing around with it, but if you write that in your answer I'll give you the check.

Comment: @Keven Awesome, so glad this worked! Edited my answer to add a link to the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exist.  You could create your own:

```
$.fn.myToggleClass = function(className, showDur, hideDur) {
    if(this.hasClass(className)){
        this.removeClass(className, hideDur);   
    } else {
        this.addClass(className, showDur);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6QqYQ/

Comment: Unfortunate.  I was trying to avoid having to use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`

Comment: @keven but this way you only have to use it in the plugin, then you just use it as you mentioned everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely an 'out of the box' suggestion, but I think it fulfills the requirement:

```
$('#e').toggleClass( "hoverE", ( $('#e').hasClass("hoverE") ? 0 : 500) );
```

(**or**) it would be a better idea to put it in a function:

```
function customToggleClass($el, classname, dur1, dur2){

    dur = $el.hasClass(classname) ? dur2 : dur1;
    $el.toggleClass(classname, dur);

    return $el;

}
```

call it like:

```
customToggleClass( $("#e"), "hoverE", 500, 0 );
```

(**OR again**) even better as a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.toggleClassFade = function(classname, dur1, dur2) {
    $.each(this, function(i, el){
        var $el = $(el);
        var dur = $el.hasClass(classname) ? dur2 : dur1;
        $el.toggleClass(classname, dur);
    });

    return this;
};
```

used like:

```
$('#e').toggleClassFade('hoverE', 500, 0)
```

(it's also chainable)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We need a little more information about your html structure to be able to answer this question. Could you [fork this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MScN/) and show us how you have your html elements set up?

Like I mentioned in my comment, using `closest` isn't actually possible here. My guess is that you were looking for the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) functions rather than `closest`. If this is the case, the fadeIn call wouldn't work if you were not in fact selecting an element. Here's a way that you can verify that you are in fact finding an element correctly using `closest`.

```
$("#e" ).hover(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest("#word")[0])
});
```

If you run this code and the result is an empty array, the selector is what went wrong. If you are getting back the element you are after, you are in quite a confusing situation (refer to my comment on the question).

EDIT: After getting a clearer understanding if the effect you were after, this is the code that ended up solving the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5MScN/5/

Comment: Just looked up next and prev in the spec.  I don't want to affect the sibling.  I want to affect the parent, so `.parent` might be the most applicable. (That exists in JQuery, right?)

Comment: jk... `.parent` didn't work.  Looks like `.closest` is the best one.